# Is nested grouping allowed in Expression Language?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I have a `range[5-7]` and a `range[11-15]`. I want to write a EL for values that do not cover these configured ranges.
I want to construct an EL like :

```
color=#{!((myBean.value ge 5 and myBean.value le 7) or (myBean.value ge 11 and myBean.value le 15))}
```

Is this a valid syntax in *Expression Language*? Can I do grouping like the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [EL 2.2 Specification](http://www.sws.bfh.ch/~fischli/courses/info/javaee/doc/expression_language-2_2-mrel-spec.pdf) 1.12 Parantheses:

"Parentheses can be used to change precedence, as in: `${(a*(b+c))}`".

So the answer is: Yes, nested grouping is allowed.

But besides reading the spec or asking question on SO, there is another way to find out such things... *trying*.